# WP Job Manager Application

Tags: wordpress, plugins, solution

I have installed a plugin called "WP Job Manager Application"- you can see it here: https://wpjobmanager.com/add-ons/applications/

This is the way the plugin is working: when a candidate is submittig an application, it gets displayed straight in the companys dashboard (every company who offers a job, has his own dashboard on the site). The application gets displayed also in the WP-backend. I need a solution, that a application first has to be accepted (by the administrator) before it gets displayed in the company dashboard. Because we verify each application for the clients and only good candidates-applications get acccepted.
Do you have an idea for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can find in Job Listing Setting that option. [image: Job Listing]